# Crystal Reports 2008 will not allow me to add a specific view as a datasource

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, database-view

I have created the following (very standard) view in my database

```
USE [Forms_New_V1.1]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vwWorkDiary]    Script Date: 21/10/2019 8:21:21 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwWorkDiary]
AS
SELECT        
    o.OrgCode,
    Orgname = o.Name,
    d.FirstName,
    d.LastName,
    d.CtrackTagID,
    frt.FatigueRule,
    VehicleName = v.Name,
    v.Registration,
    wd.StartTime,
    wd.EndTime,
    wd.StartCoord,
    wd.EndCoord,
    CurrentWorkMode = wmc.WorkModeName,
    SwitchWorkMode = wms.WorkModeName
FROM Organisation AS o 
JOIN Driver AS d ON o.OrganisationID = d.OrganisationID
JOIN WorkDiary AS wd ON d.DriverID = wd.DriverID 
JOIN Vehicle AS v ON wd.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
JOIN FatigueRuleType AS frt ON d.FatigueRuleTypeID = frt.FatigueRuleTypeID
JOIN WorkMode AS wmc ON wd.CurrentWorkMode = wmc.WorkModeID 
JOIN WorkMode AS wms ON wd.SwitchWorkMode = wms.WorkModeID
WHERE d.Active = 1
AND v.Active = 1
and frt.Active = 1
GO
```

The view works fine in the database under my credentials, and fine when I connect in as the reporting user.

When I try to add the view in Crystal I get the following error: 
[image: Error adding View to Selected Tables]

When I create a new connection under ODBC (RDO) I am able to add the view, however I cannot interact with it in the report, and verifying the datasource removes it.

[image]

The error refers to **Incorrect syntax near '.1'.**  The only .1 in the file is the `USING` statement at the top, and I don't have permission to get the database renamed.

How do I add my view to my report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a problem with the database name being invalid in the eyes of the ODBC driver.  I was eventually able to get it renamed, and the problem went away.